# Is it possible to pass information from browser to Node scope using Nightmare.js (v2 Electron)?

Tags: node.js, electron, nightmare

I am using Nightmare.js (v2.3.3) to automate a part of my workflow where I have to access a website that updates our database. I have been able to get Nightmare working for basic things like `.type`, `.click`, and `.screenshot` to validate that I am accessing these pages and inputting the information I intended.

Where I have been stuck, and the documentation seems lacking, is using `.evaluate` to extract information from the page. In the documentation it has it as:

```
.evaluate(fn [,arg1,arg2,...])

var selector = 'h1';
var text = yield nightmare
  .evaluate(function (selector) {
    // now we're executing inside the browser scope. 
    return document.querySelector(selector).innerText;
   }, selector); // <-- that's how you pass parameters from Node scope to browser scope
```

This is all well and good, but is it actually possible to go the opposite direction and pass information from browser scope to Node scope? What I would like to do is return all of the checkboxes on a page as an array, and then loop through them in the Nightmare script.

I also searched through many GitHub issues and StackOverflow questions to find an answer, and the problem seems to be that previous versions were built off of PhantomJS and v2+ is using Electron, so it is difficult to distinguish which answers actually still apply to the current version. [Here](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/89) is an answer that seemed to make sense to me, but it was in 2014 so I am thinking that most likely it was a PhantomJS version. For reference, this is the snippet that seemed to have an answer on how to transfer from browser to Node scope:

```
var p1=1,
    p2 = 2;

nightmare
  .evaluate( function(param1, param2){
        //now we're executing inside the browser scope.
        return param1 + param2;
     }, function(result){
        // now we're inside Node scope again
        console.log( result);
     }, p1, p2 // <-- that's how you pass parameters from Node scope to browser scope
  ) //end evaluate
  .run();
```

But it does not seem that the current version of Nightmare supports this `.evaluate(fn, cb, arg1, arg2,...)` format?

I would just like to know if this is possible before I drive myself crazy! Thanks for any and all help, please let me know if you need any additional information to help answer.

Comment: I don't understand. In your first snippet `text` should contain the value that was passed from page context to node context, shouldn't it? Does it?

Comment: @ArtjomB. not from my understanding. `yield nightmare` is just starting the nightmare instance to follow the chain of instructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very, very close.  One of the more recent updates is using Nightmare in a more promise-y way.  This means you don't have to handle the `.evaluate()` callback yourself, the results are passed down the chain.  Your second example, slightly tweaked:

```
nightmare = require('nightmare')();
nightmare.goto('http://example.com');

var p1=1,
    p2=2;

nightmare
  .evaluate( function(param1, param2){
        return param1 + param2;
     }, p1, p2)
  .then(function(result){
    console.log(result); //prints 3
  });
```

It's recommended you use `.then()`, but if you *really* want to use `.run()`, you can:

```
nightmare = require('nightmare')();
nightmare.goto('http://example.com');
var p1=1,
    p2=2;

nightmare
  .evaluate( function(param1, param2){
        return param1 + param2;
     }, p1, p2)
  .run(function(err, result){
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you @Ross! I was actually looking through the GitHub issues and came across a few of your answers that introduced me to `.then` and Promises. Totally new concept to me but I get why Nightmare went in that direction. So the parameter passed to `.then` is the return value of the previous task in the chain, in this case `.evaluate`? Also, what is `.run`? I could not find documentation for that anywhere, and is that not best practice for Nightmare?

Comment: Yes, the parameters of the `.then()` function will be the results from the previous action.  (It's a bit of an oversimplification, but works nicely here.)  `.run()` isn't documented as it's been slowly being deprecated.  If you're curious, the conversation about it can be found [here](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/575).

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I was banging my head against the wall for a week trying to sort this out. I will have to do some more reading into Promises and `.then` to understand it's full potential. I just set yours as the accepted answer, hopefully this can help others who are just starting out with Nightmare.

Comment: Happy to help!  For what it's worth, you _might_ want to have a gander at [nightmare-examples](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-examples), specifically the example about [native promises](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-examples/blob/master/docs/beginner/promises.md).

Comment: Thanks again! This is a huge help. I feel like this definitely should be linked to from the official documentation.

Comment: but won't `.then()` kind of `end()` the current process? Everytime I use `.then` I can't chain other methods to the nightmare instance. What if I want to extract stuff in the middle of my automation script?